# Unable to use TCP/IP between Macs over Ethernet

Tags: mac, ethernet

Let's assume we have friends A, B and C who use the newest Macbooks with factory settings.

[The firewall and stealth -mode are not the problem. Remote Apple Events and Xgrid are not needed.](https://serverfault.com/questions/31588/unable-to-use-tcp-ip-between-macs-over-ethernet/31595#31595)

They have used the ip at [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) unsuccessfully in putting these IPs to the Multiplayer settings in Age II.

They have also tried to use different hexadecimal numbers from the command

```
ifconfig
```

These problems suggest me that there is also a better way to solve the problem.
Perhaps, by etc/resolv.conf file. **It would be great to put all these settings to one or two files**, instead of trying to solve the problem graphically.

Comment: I need to first solve the following problem to get this solved: http://serverfault.com/questions/35754/unable-to-share-a-file-in-local-network-by-macs

Comment: A similar problem is at http://serverfault.com/questions/35754/unable-to-share-a-file-in-local-network-by-macs

Comment: Given the level of the question, I'd say this is a move to superuser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you have a number of issues in front of you.

- Xgrid sharing and Remote Apple Events have nothing to do with this.
- You provided a screenshot of your wired interface, but you're using wireless.
- The firewall settings likely have no effect on this.
- The hex from ifconfig is a netmask

First question, can you get to google. If not, your wireless connection is borked.

Also, are you all in the same physical location?

Comment: @dr.pooter: We are all in the same physical location. -- You are right: I use at the moment wireless connection to have internet on.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the same location, assuming you're in a home area, the issue is that your connection is probably natted, so the ip from whatsmyip.com is the NAT address, rather than the local address. If you run ifconfig, there should be a section starting inet addr: (tested on linux because I lack a mac, but it should be there all the same). That's the IP addr. you should be using to connect.

Comment: I get the following for `ifconfig`, but none of the IP addresses is mine: http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/ifconfig.png. --- No ip address gives my exact location in the map.

Comment: Are you currently in the location your having the issue with? Also, which interface are you trying to connect over?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect to ethernet if you do not have a cable plugged in! Which is why it is failing to connect!

Comment: You are completely right. My question is confusing. The screenshot was taken after I disconnected my computer from my friend's computer. -- I do not have the second computer now such that I cannot take another screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the easiest way is to have connection in the Internet by SSH.